# Insert Spark dataframe to partitioned table

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have seen methods for inserting into Hive table, such as `insertInto(table_name, overwrite =True`, but I couldn't work out how to handle the scenario below.

For the first run, a dataframe like this needs to be saved in a table, partitioned by 'date_key'. There could be one or more partitions eg `202201` and `202203`

```
+---+----------+
| id|  date_key|
+---+----------+
|  1|202201    |
|  2|202203    |
|  3|202201    |
+---+----------+
```

For subsequent run, the data comes in also like this, and I'd like to append the new data to their corresponding partitions using `date_key`

```
+---+----------+
| id|  date_key|
+---+----------+
|  4|202204    |
|  5|202203    |
|  6|202204    |
+---+----------+
```

Could you please help to shed some light on how to handle

1. if during each run there will only be new data from one partition
2. if during each run there will new data from multiple partitions, like the sample inputs above?

Many thanks for your help. Let me know if I can explain the problem better.

Edited:
I could not use `df.write.partitionBy("date_key").insertInto(table_name)`, as there was an error saying `insertInto` can not be used together with `partitionBy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my example here, first run will create new partitioned table `data`. `c2` is the partition column.

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
], 'c1 int, c2 string')
df1.show()
df1.write.partitionBy('c2').mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('data')

/
  c2=a
    part-00000-7810a4aa-a5a1-4c4f-a09a-ef86a66041c9.c000.snappy.parquet
  c2=b
    part-00000-7810a4aa-a5a1-4c4f-a09a-ef86a66041c9.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Second run, you **don't** need anything fancy, just `append` and `insertInto`. Spark knows you have `c2` is the partition column and will it properly, you don't have to tell it via `partitionBy`,

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'),
    (3, 'c'),
], 'c1 int, c2 string')
df2.show()
df2.write.mode('append').insertInto('data')

/
  c2=a
    part-00000-7810a4aa-a5a1-4c4f-a09a-ef86a66041c9.c000.snappy.parquet
    part-00000-dcd9029e-8c65-4397-bca5-ab2691ece7ff.c000.snappy.parquet
  c2=b
    part-00000-7810a4aa-a5a1-4c4f-a09a-ef86a66041c9.c000.snappy.parquet
  c2=c
    part-00000-dcd9029e-8c65-4397-bca5-ab2691ece7ff.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use mode('append'), in case of a re-run, I'd need to delete the data in that partition first, otherwise there'd be duplicates right?

Comment: Correct, it's unfortunate but yes

Comment: insertInto API has got many issues if sequence of the columns is not matched with partition column at the end.
Reference : https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-spark-insertinto-function-1870175c3ee9

Answer (score 1):

if the table is an external table you can use the following code to write the data out to the external partitioned table

```
df.write.partitionBy("date_key").mode("append").option("path","/path/to/external/table/on/hdfs").saveAsTable("table_name_here")
```

If it is a hive managed table then you can simply use the `saveAsTable` API
as follows

```
df.write.partitionBy("date_key").mode("append").saveAsTable("tableName")
```

Comment: Not entirely true. You can use a spark managed table that uses hive metastore for just that.

Comment: My answer is based on the assumption that the person is using hive